# MondoDB, export to CSV with a "join" on a value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I know the command to export via Mongo shells is

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db dbname --collection name --csv > test.csv
```

but I also need to do a "join" (in quotes because I know Mongo doesn't actually do joins so to speak". I haven't found documentation on doing this in mongo shell.

I have collections called users and another called details.
I want to export: users (name,email) and details (city,country) where users (place [object ID]) = details (_id [object ID]).

Tables look like this:

```
users
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------+
| id | name |     email     |         place         |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | bob  | bob@bob.com   | ObjectId("123456abc") |
|  2 | mark | mark@mark.com | ObjectId("654321abc") |
|  3 | dave | dave@dave.com | ObjectId("987655abc") |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------+

details
+----+-------+---------------+-----------------------+
| id | city  |    country    |          _id          |
+----+-------+---------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Perth | Australia     | ObjectId("123456abc") |
|  2 | Tokyo | Japan         | ObjectId("654321abc") |
|  3 | NY    | United States | ObjectId("987655abc") |
+----+-------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

And the result I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
+----+------+---------------+-------+---------------+
| id | name |     email     | city  |    country    |
+----+------+---------------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | bob  | bob@bob.com   | Perth | Australia     |
|  2 | mark | mark@mark.com | Tokyo | Japan         |
|  3 | dave | dave@dave.com | NY    | United States |
+----+------+---------------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: You'll need to do the join manually, either as part of a custom export script, or as a script that will insert the results to a new temporary collection that you can export with mongoexport.

Comment: @wdberkeley thank you, all sorted now :) used a `for each` to find in the collection where the objectID's were a match, then did a `merge`.

Comment: Can you share your query result?

Comment: @Igor I don't have it on hand but you'll want to use the MapReduce function to iterate through each object.